# What makes my question "Not Constructive"?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, broken-windows

I recently asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402645/why-is-there-no-filepath-class-in-the-net-framework

It was closed, and I can see that it could be perceived as soliciting discussion, because the facts to answering this are hard to come by and answers are going to be largely speculative.

However, I have also previously asked the question: [Why is there no IQueue<T> or IStack<T> interface in the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367893/why-is-there-no-iqueuet-or-istackt-interface-in-the-net-framework)

This question met with a number of useful replies and remains open.

I'm not here to demand the former question is opened, but I would like to better understand where the line is which divides these two questions.

Or, actually, they're as similar as I believe and should one be closed/reopened?

Comment: There is a tiny, but perhaps significant, difference: in the queue question you're talking about a problem you faced ("I went searching for IQueue<T>, but came back surprisingly empty-handed."), in the path one you don't, it reads more as if curiosity is your only motivation. That said I'd say both are borderline, and the main reason one is open and the other is not is that different people saw them.

Comment: Yannis, that seems a perfectly reasonable answer - shouldn't it be one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both have the same problem:

> this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or
> extended discussion.

The reason why one is open and the other is closed is simply due to a matter of *timing*. You asked the first one two years ago, when the policy was still a bit fluid (then, it seemed that *well written* questions that were subjective and argumentative (which later became 'not constructive') were allowed.  Yours was well written.

Now, the community sentiment is to close 'not constructive' questions, no matter how well written they are.

Notice that both questions elicited opinions, and in both questions there were comments that exhibited what 'not constructive' questions tend to attract: Opinions, discussion, and likely debate.

[I have closed the one that remains open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367893/why-is-there-no-iqueuet-or-istackt-interface-in-the-net-framework).  It's a great question, just not one well suited for Stack Overflow.

It appears that [Eric Lippert left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367893/why-is-there-no-iqueuet-or-istackt-interface-in-the-net-framework#comment4760669_4367916) letting you know where to ask this question, simply:

> I have no "official" position on any aspect of the design of the BCL.
> You might consider asking at the BCLTeam blog if you want an answer
> straight from the team.

So there you have it.  The question belongs as a query to the [BCL Team's blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/).

Comment: Are there any Exchange sites that would be more suited to this type of question?

Comment: @ProgrammingHero No, but I did update my question with a link to where this question would be appropriately asked.